# Updating values with a function, returning not working

Tags: javascript, closures, function-expression

So I am using a function to update my values, but I can't then get them back. I see values don't get updated, but  is there any way of saving them as a reference to the return of the function.

```
function Amphibia(wheelRadius, finsPerPropeller, propellersSpinDirection, mode) {

        this.speed = 0;
        this.mode = mode;

        var amphibiaWheel = new PropulsionUnits.Wheel(wheelRadius);
        var amphibiaPropeller = new PropulsionUnits.Propeller(finsPerPropeller, propellersSpinDirection);

        this.changeMode = function () {
            if (mode == "land") {

                mode = "water";
            }

            else if(mode == "water") {

                mode = "land";
            }

            return {

                mode: mode
            }
        }

        this.accelerate = function() {
            if(this.mode == "water"){
                this.speed += amphibiaPropeller.acceleration;
            }
            else if(this.mode == "land"){
                this.speed += 4*amphibiaWheel.acceleration;
            }
        }

        this.changePropellerSpinDirection = function() {

            amphibiaPropeller.changeSpinDirection();
        }

        return {

            speed: this.speed,
            mode: this.mode,
            changeMode: this.changeMode,
            accelerate: this.accelerate,
            changePropellerSpinDirection: this.changePropellerSpinDirection
        }

    }
```

So here I am experiencing problems with changing the mode and the changeMode function expression. Mode in it should refer to this.mode and then I should be able to update the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mode` and `this.mode` are *not* the same.  In your functions you are checking/setting values on `mode` and `this.mode`, separately.

Either should work fine, as long as you're using one or the other, in the same place, the same way.

### Edit

```
var Amphibia = function (wheelRadius, finsPerPropeller, propellersSpinDirection, mode) {

    var amphibia = this,
        MODES = { LAND : "land", WATER : "water" };

    amphibia.getMode = function () { return mode; };
    amphibia.setMode = function (val) { mode = val; };

    amphibia.changeMode = function () {
        amphibia.setMode((mode === MODES.LAND) ? MODES.WATER : MODES.LAND);
    };
};


var amphibia = new Amphibia("", "", "", "land");

amphibia.getMode();    // "land"
amphibia.changeMode();
amphibia.getMode();    // "water"
```

`mode` is now 100% private, and unique to that instance.

If you don't need it to be, then you can append it to `this`, if you'd like.

But here's your problem:

```
var Amphibia = function () {
    var amphibia = this,
        amphibiaPropeller = new Propeller(  );

    // mode, getMode, setMode, etc...

    amphibia.accelerate = function () {
        if (amphibia.getMode() === "water") {
            this.speed += amphibiaPropeller.acceleration;
        }
    };
};

var amphibia = new Amphibia();
var bob = { speed : 0 };
bob.accelerate = amphibia.accelerate;

bob.accelerate();
// if amphibia.mode === "water", bob.speed += amphibiaPropeller.acceleration

bob.speed; // === amphibiaPropeller.acceleration


setTimeout(amphibia.accelerate, 10); // call amphibia.accelerate in ~10ms
// if amphibia.mode === "water", window.speed += amphibiaPropeller.acceleration
window.speed; // === amphibiaPropeller.acceleration
```

Be consistent in how you refer to things.
Don't mix `self` and `this`, unless you ***intend*** to get those side-effects...
And unless you have a very, very good reason to do so (like you're building a framework/engine, not the modules/classes of the game/simulation which *use* the engine; ie: the difference between building jQuery and building something *with* jQuery), then you should probably avoid doing it.

If you have closure ("private") state that you want to expose to the outside world, all you need is a function that returns that value, and/or one that sets it.
All of a sudden, the differences between `self` and `this` and what is which, when, all go away, as long as you are consistent with how you use them, and you know what the value of `this` is going to be, every time you ***call*** the method.

Notice I'm not returning anything...
When I use `new`, the value of `this` (`amphibia`/`self`) gets returned by default.

If you want to use private values, and return a "Revealing Module" (which is what I typically prefer), then you can simply do this:

```
var Amphibia = function (mode) {
    var getMode = function () { return mode; },
        setMode = function (val) { mode = val; },
        changeMode = function () {
            setMode( mode === "water" ? "land" : "water" );
        };

    return {
        getMode : getMode,
        setMode : setMode,
        changeMode : changeMode
    };
};

var amphibia = new Amphibia("water");
// `new` won't do any harm, but you can also not use it,
// without it saving everything to `window`

amphibia.getMode(); // "water"
amphibia.changeMode();
amphibia.getMode(); // "land"
```

Or, maybe if you want that to look a little more like a module/component...

```
    return {
        mode : { get : getMode, set : setMode, switch : changeMode }
    };


var amphibia = Amphibia("land");
amphibia.mode.get(); // "land"
amphibia.mode.switch();
amphibia.mode.get(); // "water"


var bob = { };
bob.switchAmphibiaMode = amphibia.mode.switch;
bob.switchAmphibiaMode();
amphibia.mode.get(); // "land"

setTimeout(amphibia.mode.switch, 10);
setTimeout(function () { console.log(amphibia.mode.get()); }, 20);

// 10ms amphibia.mode.switch();
// 20ms console.log(amphibia.mode.get());
//          > "water"
```

...or whatever other structure you'd like.
You don't need a `this` at all.

But `this` is something to be very, very careful with in JavaScript, because the meaning of `this` changes every time you call a function, and if half of the code uses `this` and half uses `self`, you're bound for some surprises.

Comment: when I log this.mode in this.changeMode function expression it returns  undefined, so I guess I can't use this.mode only, and with a variable not this. I can't then later return it out of the module...

Comment: @user3127242 If you are not calling `new Amphibia` in your code, then `this === window;` which is bad.  Also, if you are not calling `var myAmphibia = new Amphibia(/*...*/); myAmphibia.accelerate();` but rather stuffing `.accelerate` in a callback (`setTimeout(myAmphibia.accelerate, 0);`), then `this === window;`.  Both of these are *very* not good. Your module is full of `mode; self.mode; this.mode;`, and it shouldn't be. Either this is a **constructor** `new Amphibia( );` where `this` is acceptable, or it's a **function** where `this` isn't. There are exceptions, but the rules come first.

Comment: @user3127242 Also, when you make `var self = this;`, it's the `this` at time of construction. When you use `this` inside of a method: `if (self.mode /*...*/) { this.mode; }` you're saying "If the initial object's mode ... then set the calling object's mode..." There's no guarantee they are the same object.

Comment: @user3127242 See the above edit for why your current solution is still bound to explode on you, at some point in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the answer myself! :) So basicly this in the function constructor refers to Amphibia and this in the this.changeMode function expression refers to object window. Therefore we can define a variable self = this; in the constructor, so we can refer to the same thing in the function expression, as in the function. I explained it a bit awful, but here is my fixed code ;)

```
function Amphibia(wheelRadius, finsPerPropeller, propellersSpinDirection, mode) {

        this.speed = 0;
        var self = this;
        self.mode = mode;

        var amphibiaWheel = new PropulsionUnits.Wheel(wheelRadius);
        var amphibiaPropeller = new PropulsionUnits.Propeller(finsPerPropeller, propellersSpinDirection);

        this.changeMode = function () {


            if (self.mode == "land") {

                self.mode = "water";
            }

            else if(self.mode == "water") {

                self.mode = "land";
            }

        }

        this.accelerate = function() {
            if(self.mode == "water"){
                this.speed += amphibiaPropeller.acceleration;
            }
            else if(self.mode == "land"){
                this.speed += 4*amphibiaWheel.acceleration;
            }
        }

        this.changePropellerSpinDirection = function() {

            amphibiaPropeller.changeSpinDirection();
        }

        return {

            speed: this.speed,
            mode: this.mode,
            changeMode: self.changeMode,
            accelerate: this.accelerate,
            changePropellerSpinDirection: this.changePropellerSpinDirection
        }

    }
```